# Porque o tamanho do JFrame excede o tamanho de seu ContentPane, mesmo ele possuindo tamanho definido?

Tags: java, swing, redimensionamento

Notei um comportamento estranho entre containers no swing.

Para exemplificar o teste, criei um `JFrame` e um `JPanel`, e defini o painel como *contentPane* do `JFrame`. Defini o tamanho preferido e máximo do `JPanel` como 400,300. Tudo isso pode ser visto no exemplo abaixo:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ExcessiveSpacePanelTest {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;

    public void initGUI(){

        frame =  new JFrame();

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 1));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 300));


        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();

        System.out.println("panel size: [" + panel.getSize().width + "," + panel.getSize().height +"]");
        System.out.println("frame size: [" + frame.getSize().width + "," + frame.getSize().height+"]");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->{
            new ExcessiveSpacePanelTest().initGUI();
        });
    }
}
```

O resultado da tela é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pra minha surpresa, a saida no terminal é:

> panel size: [400,300]
>   frame size: [416,338]

Não entendi porque o frame adicionou este espaço extra, mesmo não tendo nada no componente que force o frame a se redimensionar.

Tentei definir bordas zeradas no painel adicionando a linha `panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));` antes do `pack()`mas mesmo assim o resultado é o mesmo.

O problema em ocorrer isso é que o java está me dando uma falsa informação, visto que o painel está se dimensionando no tamanho do frame, e pelo resultado acima, vimos que os dois não possuem o mesmo tamanho.

As duas medidas estão sendo informadas corretamente? Por que isto ocorre?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está certo. Este espaço extra é referente **as bordas da janela**, estas bordas contam no tamanho.

Por exemplo, no Windows 10, as janelas têm uma borda de 1px em cada lado. Fora isso, tem mais uma borda invisível de 7px pra firmar o ponteiro do mouse na hora de alterar o tamanho da janela. Somando estas bordas, tem-se 16, que é exatamente a diferença entre o área utilizável do `Frame` o tamanho real dele no meu exemplo.

É possível capturar o tamanho da área "utilizável" do JFrame utilizando `getContentPane()` mesmo sem pré-definir um componente para ser o `ContentPane`. Ou seja, já existe ali um `Panel` que ocupa o tamanho máximo "utilizável" da janela.

Veja um exemplo

```
public void initGUI(){
    frame =  new JFrame();

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    frame.pack();

    System.out.println("Content pane size: [" + frame.getContentPane().getSize().width + ", " + frame.getContentPane().getSize().height + "]");
    System.out.println("frame size: [" + frame.getSize().width + "," + frame.getSize().height+"]");

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

A saída é:

> Content pane size: [384, 261]
>   frame size: [400,300]

Comment: Mas ai você definiu o tamanho do frame, o que força o layoutmanager a reduzir o tamanho interno dos componentes. O problema desse comportamento é que o JPanel acusa um tamanho, mas na imagem vemos outro(a largura dele não está sendo 400 e sim 416)

Comment: A largura de quem? Do meu frame?

Comment: Sim, a saida mostra uma diferença de 16px(que não é pouca coisa) mas na imagem o painel tem a mesma largura que o frame. Isso que me gera problema, pois eu trabalho com o tamanho do painel, mas o tamanho definido(400) não é o exibido(416)