# Largura de JPanel excedendo a dimensão definida no getPreferredSize()

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Estou tentando criar um joguinho breakout, já fiz boa parte da lógica, só que descobri um problema incômodo relativo ao tamanho do painel da "cena" do jogo.

Segue minha classe `Board`, que é o painel onde todo os componentes do jogo são distribuidos:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Board extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public final int WIDTH = 400;
    public final int HEIGHT = 300;
    private final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 20;

    private Timer timer;
    public Ball ball;
    public Paddle paddle;

    private JLabel scoreLabel, score;   

    public Board() {

        paddle = new Paddle(this);
        ball = new Ball(this);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));

        scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: ");
        scoreLabel.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(12f));
        score = new JLabel();
        score.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(12f));
        this.add(scoreLabel);
        this.add(score);

        this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                paddle.keyPressed(e);
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
                    starGame();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                paddle.keyReleased(e);
            }
        });

        ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                updateBoard();
                repaint();
            }
        };

        timer = new Timer(UPDATE_INTERVAL, action);

        setFocusable(true);

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    private void updateBoard() {
        ball.move();
        paddle.move();
        repaint();
    }

    public void gameOver() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Game Over");
        newGame();
    }

    public void starGame() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        timer.stop();
    }

    public void newGame() {
        stop();
        paddle = new Paddle(this);
        ball = new Ball(this);
        repaint();
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        ball.setSpeed(speed);
    }


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ball.paint(g2);
        paddle.paint(g2);
    }
}
```

No código acima, pode ser visto que defini largura e altura baseado em valores fixos, e sobrescrevi o método `preferredSize()` para que fossem respeitadas essas medidas.

O problema é que toda a lógica(colisões com extremidades da tela) é baseado nessas medidas que defini no `JPanel`, mas por algum motivo está ficando um espaço adicional à direita, como pode ser visto pela colisão da bolinha e do bastão no canto direito no gif abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu pensei que o problema poderia estar relacionado com [esta outra dúvida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203681/28595), mas o espaço extra ocorre dentro do `JPanel` e não tem relação com o `JFrame`.

Na classe `Ball`, a formula que estou utilizando para detectar o limite do canto direito e inverter a direção está no método `move()` de ambas as classes:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Ball {

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 15;
    private final int DIAMETER = 30;
    private int xSpeed = 1;
    private int ySpeed = 1;

    private final Board board;
    private final Paddle paddle;


    public Ball(Board board) {
        this.board = board;
        this.paddle = board.paddle;
        y = paddle.getTopY() - DIAMETER;
        x = board.WIDTH / 2 - DIAMETER / 2;
    }

    public void move() {

        if (x >= board.WIDTH - DIAMETER || x <= 0) {
            xSpeed = -xSpeed;
        }

        if (y < 15) {
            ySpeed = -ySpeed;
        }

        if (y + DIAMETER > paddle.getTopY() + paddle.HEIGHT) {
            board.gameOver();
        }

        if (collision()) {

            float paddleCenter = paddle.getX() + (paddle.WIDTH/2);

            float relativePos = (this.x + (DIAMETER/2) - paddleCenter) / (paddle.WIDTH/2);

            if((relativePos > 0 && xSpeed < 0) || (relativePos < 0 && xSpeed > 0)){
                xSpeed = -xSpeed;
            }

            ySpeed = -ySpeed;
            y = paddle.getTopY() - DIAMETER;
        }

        x += xSpeed;
        y += ySpeed;
    }

     [...]
}
```

Classe `Paddle`:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Paddle {

    private int x = 0;
    private final int topY;
    public final int WIDTH = 100;
    public final int HEIGHT = 10;
    private int direction = 0;

    private Board board;

    public Paddle(Board board) {
        this.board = board;
        topY = board.HEIGHT;
        x = board.WIDTH / 2 - WIDTH / 2;

    }

    public void move() {
        if (x + direction >= 0 && x + direction <= board.WIDTH - WIDTH) {
            x = x + direction;
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.fillRect(x, topY, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            direction = -5;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            direction = 5;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        direction = 0;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, topY, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public int getTopY() {
        return topY;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Como removo este espaço, mantendo o tamanho do JPanel fixo?

Como um exemplo testável ficaria grande na pergunta,adicionei no [Gist](https://gist.github.com/diegofelipem/898acf5712638871b32145d133b7cc23) um código executável contendo todas as classes(`Ball`, `Paddle` e `Board`) envolvidas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme [resposta pergunta análoga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43919349/5524514) no SOEn, o espaçamento de fato existia, devido ao fato de eu invocar o método `pack()`, que é o responsável por dimensionar a janela e todos os seus componentes, e depois alterar definições do frame, como `setResizable(false)`, na classe que inicia a aplicação:

```
public void initGui() {
    frame = new JFrame("Tennis Game");

    frame.setJMenuBar(getMenu());

    this.boardGame = new Board();
    frame.setContentPane(boardGame);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false); //esta chamada após o pack() é que ocasiona o erro
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Ao chamar `setResizable(false)`, o espaço extra dedicado a bordas do sistema para redimensionar a janela deixa de ser necessário, e este espaço acaba sendo somado ao tamanho do Frame, resultando no espaço além do que eu defini para o `JPanel`.

A solução foi apenas passar a chamada do `pack()` como a última, antecedendo apenas o `setvisible`:

```
//frame.pack(); 
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
frame.setResizable(false); 
frame.pack(); 
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Alterando apenas isso em todo o código, o problema da colisão da bolinha e do `Paddle` funcionam como esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A idéia de adicionar um modificador de tamanho relativo sugerida pelo [brow-joe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/203935/28595) também foi boa e efetiva, mas a causa do problema era um pequeno errinho na ordem de chamar os métodos que renderizam a aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Á lógica está certa, existe apenas uma condição no método `move` de `Ball` que pode ser alterada, na verdade quando você faz:

```
if (x >= board.WIDTH - DIAMETER || x <= 0) {
    ....
}
```

está ficando uma "sobra" de 30px antes de realmente acontecer a colisão em x com a lateral.

Eu recomento utilizar um percentual do diâmetro total da seguinte maneira:

```
double frequency = 0.5;
if (x >= board.WIDTH - (DIAMETER * frequency) || x <= 0) {
    ...
}
```

A frequencia é o percentual de 0 a 1, quanto mais proximo de 0 maior será a sobra de pixels e quanto mais proximo de 1 menor será a sobra de pixels

Você vai precisar fazer o mesmo no `Paddle`, porém como o tamanho dele é maior, vc pode utilizar uma frequencia maior.

por exemplo no método `move` do `Paddle`

```
double frequency = 0.9;
if ((x * frequency) + direction >= 0 && x + direction <= board.WIDTH - (WIDTH * frequency)) {
    ...
}
```

Segue o gif com as configurações de 50% (0.5) em `Ball` e com 90% (0.9) em `Paddle`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58796/discussion-on-answer-by-brow-joe-largura-de-jpanel-excedendo-a-dimensao-definida)