# Como mudar cor de borda e título JFrame no Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Gostaria de saber como mudo a cor da borda e do título de um JFrame no Java. Encontrei apenas informação de como retirar a borda e o título, mas como alterar a cor não. Atualmente estou usando o Eclipse.

Comment: Tem alguma ferramenta que ajude a mudar a cor da borda? Ainda sou iniciante no Java.

Comment: Eu já respondi a sua duvidana resposta abaixo, não há mais o que esclarecer com o que foi perguntado.

Comment: Obrigado. -----

Answer (score 2):

Isto não é possível. A borda da janela do JFrame(onde fica os botoes de fechar, minimizar, maximizar) é controlada pelo *look and feel* do sistema operacional no qual a aplicação está executando.

Pode encontrar alguns [*look and feels*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) que até alterem a aparência da janela, mas a barra de titulo é sempre controlada pelo sistema operacional em execução. O máximo que conseguirá é utilizar *look and feels* nativos do próprio java, como o metal, que por serem [cross-plataform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-platform), dão aparência própria a barra.

---

**Referencias:**

- [how can i change the color of titlebar in JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482971/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-titlebar-in-jframe)
- [Change JFrame border in UIDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18302639/5524514)
- [Porque o tamanho do JFrame excede o tamanho de seu ContentPane, mesmo ele possuindo tamanho definido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203681/28595)

Comment: Mas como diversos aplicativos para Windows tem essa propriedade alterada? O Chrome por exemplo altera isso facilmente. Programas como Steam, Baidu Antivírus e Skype também são outros exemplos de programas que tem a borda e o título totalmente customizado.

Comment: @GabrielAugusto nenhum deles e feito em java-swing e muito menos utiliza jframe.